# Hive table validation

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an hive table with some records. 
I validate the table using a script, and the result is stored in another table. 
Basically  I have to get a count of both these tables, and find the difference.
The difference will then be compared to a threshold value.

Based on that result, table will be used for analysis or rejected.

The threshold value is a measure of the bad records that the table can contain.

Example:-
Assume that table A has 100 records.
the records are validated and the valid records are stored in another table B. 
let's say that table B has 70 records. 
so difference is 100-70=30.

let's assume that threshold is 20(means maximum of 20 bad records can be present), 
So in this case, table will be rejected.

how to perform this?

Comment: Are you creating a new table? inserting into an existing table? is it a partitioned table? Are you inserting to a specific partition?

Comment: I'm creating a new table and storing the valid records in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hive.stats.autogather` is set to `true` then the table statistics is gather  automatically, including `numRows`.
All you have to do in that case is to check the statistics and take what ever decision you want.

If this is **not the case** than just execute 2 `select count(*)` queries, e.g. -

```
src_numRows=$(hive -e "select count(*) from src")
trg_numRows=$(hive -e "select count(*) from trg")
```

P.s.

It can be done is a single query but I think it would be better to save the raw results other than just the diff.

```
select  s.cnt - t.cnt   as diff

from                (select count(*) as cnt from src) s 
        cross join  (select count(*) as cnt from trg) t
;
```

#### Demo

**create source table**

```
create table src 
as 
select  i+1 as n
from    (select 1) x lateral view posexplode(split(space(100-1),' ')) pe as i,x
;
```

**create target table**

```
create table trg 
as 
select  * 
from    src
where   n > 30
;
```

---

**Check tables` statistics**

**bash**

```
src_numRows=$(hive -e "show tblproperties src ('numRows')")
trg_numRows=$(hive -e "show tblproperties trg ('numRows')")

printf "src:%g,trg:%g,diff:%g\n" ${src_numRows} ${trg_numRows} $((src_numRows-trg_numRows))
```

> src:100,trg:70,diff:30

**Another option is to check the statistics directly from the metasotre**

**MySQL**

```
select  t.TBL_NAME
       ,tp.PARAM_VALUE 

from            DBS             d 

        join    TBLS            t   
        on      t.DB_ID = d.DB_ID 

        join    TABLE_PARAMS    tp  
        on      tp.TBL_ID = t.TBL_ID 

where   d.NAME = 'default' 
    and t.TBL_NAME in ('src','trg') 
    and tp.PARAM_KEY = 'numRows'
;
```

---

```
+----------+-------------+
| TBL_NAME | PARAM_VALUE |
+----------+-------------+
| src      | 100         |
| trg      | 70          |
+----------+-------------+
```